# JSTL iterate over list of objects

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, iteration

I am getting a list 'myList' of objects in jsp. Objects I am getting belongs to e.g 'MyClass'.
I want to iterate over this list through JSTL.

JSP code is below :

```
<c:forEach items="myList" var="element">    
  <tr>
    <td>${element.getStatus()}</td>
    <td>${element.getRequestType()}</td>
    <td>${element.getRequestedFor()}</td>
    <td>${element.getTimeSubmitted()}</td>
  </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

I am getting exception :

```
 00000024 WebApp  E   [Servlet Error]-[/requestHistory.jsp]: com.ibm.ws.jsp.translator.JspTranslationException: JSPG0227E: Exception caught while translating /requestHistory.jsp:  
    /requestHistory.jsp(31,6) --> JSPG0122E: Unable to parse EL function ${UserProcessRequests.getStatus()}.
```

Taglib I am using are :

```
 <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
 <%@ page isELIgnored="false"%>
```

Answer (score 70, accepted):

There is a mistake. See this line `<c:forEach items="${myList}" var="element">`.  ${} around 'myList' was missing.

```
<c:forEach items="${myList}" var="element"> 
  <tr>
    <td>${element.status}</td>
    <td>${element.requestType}</td>
    <td>${element.requestedFor}</td>
    <td>${element.timeSubmitted}</td>
  </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: I have a doubt here, what is myList here, is session variable name?

Answer (score 14):

replace it with

```
`${element.status}`
```

JSTL will look for standard getters setters on its own