# Iterating through an ArrayList<Object> "cannot be resolved or is not a field"

Tags: java, jsp, session

**Error**

```
An error occurred at line: 18 in the jsp file: /BookStoreHome.jsp
title cannot be resolved or is not a field
15: <% 
16: ArrayList<Book> book_list = (ArrayList<Book>)session.getAttribute("books"); 
17: for (int i = 0; i < book_list.size(); i++) {%>
18: <%= book_list.get(i).title %>,
19: <% } %>
20: 
21: </body>
```

First I am setting the books as an ArrayList and storing in a session.
**User Logic Class**

```
ArrayList<Book> book_list = bsl.selectBooks();
session.setAttribute("books", book_list);
```

**Book Class**

```
public class Book {

    public String isbn;
    public String title;
    public double price;
    public String genre;
    public int format;
    public String publisher;
    public int publisherYear;
    public int count;
    public String author;
    public String date;


    public Book(String _isbn, String _title, double _price, String _genre, int _format, 
            String _publisher, int _publisheryear, int _count, String _author){
        title = _title;
        isbn = _isbn;
        price = _price;
        genre = _genre;
        format = _format;
        publisher = _publisher;
        publisherYear = _publisheryear;
        count = _count;
        author = _author;
    }
```

Comment: why use Scriptlet when there is Jstl. See this as advice from experts http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4535423/jstl-vs-jsp-scriptlets and this for your possible alternative http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5893183/jstl-iterate-over-list-of-objects

Comment: This works fine for me. Try to recompile your `Book` class.

Comment: In the school project I don't think he wants us to use JSTL @GauravGupta

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Hmm, that is weird, I am still having the issue, would you have any idea what else could be the problem.

Comment: Do you multiple `Book` classes? Are you importing the right one in the JSP?