# How can I iterate list object in JSP?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have ShoppingCart class:

```
package shoppingcart;

import models.CD;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

public class ShoppingCart {

    private List<CD> shoppingCartItemList ;
    private long totalPrice ; 

    public ShoppingCart() 
    {
        shoppingCartItemList = new ArrayList<CD>() ;
        totalPrice = 0 ; 
    }

    public void addCdToCart(CD cd)
    {
        shoppingCartItemList.add(cd) ;
        totalPrice += cd.getPrice();
    }

    public List<CD> getShoppingCartItems() 
    {
        return this.shoppingCartItemList ;
    }

    public long getTotalPrice() 
    {
        return totalPrice;
    }

}
```

I use this class in a servlet:

```
ShoppingCart shoppingCart = new ShoppingCart();

CD cd = new CD(1, "DAVID", 10, 1);
shoppingCart.addCdToCart(cd);

request.getSession().setAttribute("shoppingCart", shoppingCart);
request.setAttribute("servletMessage", "CD added to Cart");
```

As you can see, I have a list and i have to iterate this in my jsp. I import the ShoppingCard class in my jsp:

```
<%@ page import="shoppingcart.ShoppingCart"%>
<c:forEach items="${shoppingCart.getShoppingCartItems}" var="cart">
<form method="POST"     action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/removeFromCart">
<input type="hidden" name="cdId" value="${cart.title}" />
<tr>
<td><c:out value="${cart.title}" /></td>
<td align="center"><c:out value="${cart.category}" /></td>
<td align="center"><c:out value="${cart.price}" /></td>
<td align="center" width="25%"><input type="submit" value="Remove"  name="action" style="height:30px; width: 70px;font-size:10pt;"></td>
</tr>
</form>
</c:forEach>
```

I get this error:

```
org.apache.jasper.el.JspPropertyNotFoundException: /myCart.jsp(85,4) '${shoppingCart.getShoppingCartItems}' Property 'getShoppingCartItems' not found on type shoppingcart.ShoppingCart. What can I solve this problem?
```

Should I change something?

Edited because of the extra added code.

Comment: Try adding a getShoppingCartItemList method to the shoppingCart class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shopping cart is stored in an attribute named "shoppingCart". So it should be something like

```
<c:forEach items="${shoppingCart.xxx}" ...
```

where xxx is the property allowing to access the list inside the ShoppinCart instance. But you don't have such a property. So, add the following method the ShoppingCart:

```
 public List<CD> getElements() {
     return this.shoppingCartItemList;
 }
```

and use

```
<c:forEach items="${shoppingCart.elements}" ...
```

Note that naming "shoppingCartItemList" an attribute of the class "ShoppinCart" is redundant and verbose. That's why I chose to name the getter `getElements()`: `shoppingCart.elements` is much easier to read and natural than `shoppingCart.shoppingCartItemList`. You should rename the private field to `elements` as well.

Comment: I created  public List<CD> getShoppingCartItems() 
 {
  return this.shoppingCartItemList ;
 } This function but I get this error: getShoppingCartItems' not found on type shoppingcart.ShoppingCart

Comment: Edit your question, show the modified code, and the full stack trace of the exception. Note that the getter in my answer is named `getElements()`, and that the foreach uses `items="shoppinCart.elements"`. And re-read the last part of my answer: you shouldn't persist in your bad naming choices.

Comment: So, I'll rewrite it a third time, hoping that you finally read it. My getter is named `getElements()`, but in the JSP EL, I use `shoppingCart.elements`. Since you named your getter `getShoppingCartItems()`, you should use `shoppingCart.shoppingCartItems` in the JSP EL.

Comment: There is no way you get an error saying *'${shoppingCart.getShoppingCartItems}' Property 'getShoppingCartItems' not found on type shoppingcart.ShoppingCart* if the code uses `${shoppingCart.shoppingCartItems}`. So, once again, what is the error message, and what is the code?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use JSTL for iterating objects in JSP

here is a case similar to this:
[JSTL iterate over list of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5893183/jstl-iterate-over-list-of-objects)

here is an example:
http://www.journaldev.com/2090/jstl-tutorial-with-examples-jstl-core-tags

here is a jstl tutorial:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_standard_tag_library.htm

it has more things to have a better source code.
I hope this can help you...